# Implementing a background thread - Slow process

Tags: java, android

So I have a method in my android program that takes a long time to process since it has some implementation in fetching data from the internet.

I wanted to put this process in the background and have it update the UI when it completes but not prevent the user from seeing the program.

The problem is though I just have it all in one method (This function that takes a few seconds). I know it works properly and from what I've seen with `ASyncTask` I would need to split it up for it to utilize `ASyncTask`.

Is there anyway I can just do something so that this one in particular method can just be put on another thread? It seems extraneous to have to split up something that already works :-/

Edit: Solved, I ended up just using ASyncTask and taking the time to understand it. I only need to tinker two or three lines and it works perfectly now.

Comment: Are you more concerned with doing it properly or with having a lesser amount of methods?

Comment: And learn to use line-breaks...

Comment: Why did I get downvoted? My apologies for not using the line breaks. Haven't posted a question in a while. I'm just looking for a solution for it but I'm afraid to screw up what already works :-/

Comment: not sure why the downvotes, seems like a fair question although broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just use a `Thread` and `Handler` combo

Comment: See I was looking more into this but I keep having trouble understanding how to implement them. Do you have useful resources for this besides the android development docs?

Comment: @kentoe what are you having issues with, their are various books you could buy such as Professional Android Development or the Commonsware subscription that have examples of both `ASyncTask` and `Thread`  If you have specific questions you can ask them here.

Comment: My issue is that when I start the application I call a method that parses xml out on a server. This takes a while, but it's not split up into different parts it's all in one method to execute. I notice that when I look into ASyncTask that I need three/four different parts though for the one method to go into a background thread.

I know my method works properly and I'm afraid of breaking it because I spent so much time getting it to work. I just execute one method and I just wanted to know if it's possible to easily put that one method into another thread of background task when I execute it.

Comment: @kento you don't have to actually use all the callbacks in `ASyncTask` just throw everything in doInBackground

Comment: Thanks for replying and such, I ended up doing exactly that. I learned ASyncTask a bit more and now it works flawlessly and makes everything a lot better.